# ¿Cómo activar varios rangos simultáneamente en Google Sheets con Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, macros

Busco seleccionar varios rangos a la vez con un ciclo for, pero lo único que hace este ciclo es que selecciona uno por uno. La idea es que empiece en la "fila 31" lo seleccione y luego salte 22 filas para seleccionar la "fila 53" y así sucesivamente.

```
function obtenerRango() {

  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //var rango = hoja.getRange(31, 4, 1, 13).activate();

  for (i = 31; i < 600; i += 22) {
    hoja.getRange(i, 4, 1, 13).activate();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para seleccionar múltiples celdas utiliza un arreglo de rangos. La idea es colocar en un arreglo todos los rangos que necesitas seleccionar, y luego activarlos todos usando `getRangeList(lista).activate()`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo modificando levemente tu código:

```
function obtenerRango() {
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  var rangeList = [];
  for (i = 31; i < 600; i += 22) {
    rangeList.push(hoja.getRange(i, 4, 1, 13).getA1Notation());
  }
  hoja.getRangeList(rangeList).activate();
}
```